# Find the volume with an integral

Tags: calculus

I've been given two functions $y^2=(x+4)^3$ and $x=0$.
I need to find the volume of a shape obtained by rotating these curves along the y-axis. First off I found that $x=y^{2/3}-4$, and $x(y)=0$ when $y=8$ or $y=-8$. So my question is that if I now use the formula $V=\pi\int_a^b (x(y))^2dy$, should the bounds be $a=0$ and $b=8$, since the graph is symmetrial and then I multiply the answer by 2 to get the full volume? If I set the bounds $a=-8$ and $b=8$, I just get 0.

Comment: no problem if you take a=0 and b=8 and double the result.

Comment: Show us your work. You shouldn't get $0$ as the volume